# MUI TextField breaks Validation Schema when addind Onchange

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, formik, yup

this is my first thread I hope i do this right,
I am trying to send data for mysql server and it goes well, however when I use TextField from MUI the validation schema starts looking funny and gives error ("require field") even with the text there, However if i submit the data the mysql receives the data.

and here goes the code...

```
//uses Express send data to mysql

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from "axios"
import { Container, Grid, Typography} from '@material-ui/core';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import Textfield from './Forms/IndividualComponents/TextField';
import Button from './Forms/IndividualComponents/Button'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formWrapper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(10),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(8),
  },
}));

const INITIAL_FORM_STATE = {
  firstName: ''
  
};


const FORM_VALIDATION = Yup.object().shape({
  firstName: Yup.string("enter your first name")
    .required('Required')
  
});

export default function ImagesUpload() {
  
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState()
  const [submitform, setSubmitForm] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      const result = await axios.get('/submitform')
      setSubmitForm(result.data.submitform)
    })()
  }, [])

  const submit = async event => {
    
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('firstName', firstName)
    const result = await axios.post('/submitForm', data)
    setSubmitForm([result.data, ...submitform]) 
    console.log(firstName)   
  }
  
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (    
    
    
    <Grid item xs={12}>
    <Container maxWidth="md">
            <div className={classes.formWrapper}>
            <Formik
            initialValues={{
              ...INITIAL_FORM_STATE
            }}
            validationSchema={FORM_VALIDATION}           
            >
            <Form onSubmit={submit}>
                
            <Grid container spacing={2}>

            <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography>
              Personal details
            </Typography>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Textfield          
                      name="firstName"
                      label="First Name"                    
                      value={firstName}                     
                      onChange={(event => setFirstName(event.target.value)  )}  
                      type="text"          
                    />
                
                
              </Grid>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
                                           
              </Grid>
              
                
            </Form>
            </Formik>
            <main>
        {submitform.map(post => (
          
          <figure key={post.id}>           
            <figcaption>{post.firstName}</figcaption>
          </figure>
        ))}
        
      </main>
            </div>
            </Container>
            </Grid>

             
      
    
  );
}
```

the Textfield im using is a costum one with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useField } from 'formik';

const TextfieldWrapper = ({
  name,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const [field, mata] = useField(name);

  const configTextfield = {
    ...field,
    ...otherProps,
    fullWidth: true,
    
  };

  if (mata && mata.touched && mata.error) {
    configTextfield.error = true;
    configTextfield.helperText = mata.error;
  }

  return (
    <TextField {...configTextfield} />
  );
};

export default TextfieldWrapper;
```

the problem here is the onChange: If i don't use it I cant setFirstName to send the data, but when I use it it breaks the validation... I tried everything  i can find online but this is taking away my sleep for real ! :)

Comment: I did bad the formatting! trying to fix that...

Comment: Why don't you follow the example in their docs? https://formik.org/docs/examples/with-material-ui Note how they set the change handler.